# Two Bootstrap button side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a **Submit** and **Cancel** button next to each other, maybe 5 pixels in between.
I wrote this that you can see in Live code:

http://www.bootply.com/Y3t35NGADa

But the distance between the two buttons is a lot ! I want them much closer to each other. I did try setting `padding-right` or `margin-right` on the **Submit** button but did not do anything!

Comment: [mcve] goes in your question

Comment: Also, you created two columns in your example. Why did you do that and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 5):

It is because u have given col-xs-4 that's why two buttons are taking 4 column space.

**Option 1:**
Here is your answer

```
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <button id="submit" name="button" value="register" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <button id="cancel" name="button" value="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

OPtion 2:
Place the two button next to each other

```
<div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button id="submit" name="button" value="register" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  <button id="cancel" name="button" value="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do this with bootstrap class button-group.

```
<div class="button-group ">                
                 <button id="submit" name="button" value="register" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>               
                <button id="cancel" name="button" value="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>           
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put them in separated columns, just keep them next each other like this:

```
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <button id="submit" name="button" value="register" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              <button id="cancel" name="button" value="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two buttons next to each other as much as possible I use this http://www.bootply.com/oX77TSFRY5:

```
<style>
  .clear {
    clear: both;    
  }
</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button value="cancel" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Cancel</button> 
    <button value="register" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Submit</button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

If you want the distance 5px like you mention in your question just remove `pull-left` classes.

[image]